# Parsing JSON from AJAX, potential man in the middle with eval?

Tags: ajax, json, xss, eval

I'm writing some AJAX; the server returns JSON (that I also wrote, and as such is sanitary JSON). Under these conditions it seems I can use eval just fine, however I worry that there may be some sort of man in the middle attack on my clients, substituting their JSON for mine. I suppose if there is a man in the middle, they can just as easily substitute their own javascript files as they can change my JSON...

So I guess if anyone can confirm I'm right, that so long as I can trust the server's JSON I can trust the JSON (and thus use eval), then that'd be nice.

Answer (score 1):

It's [right there](http://www.json.org/js.html), do you really want to chance it?

Comment: I'm not certain, how much is 2.5k while working in a mobile development environment? And is there really any risk? 2.5k may not be much, but if there's honestly no serious risk, then why would I?